# iOS - Showing info from tableView didSelect

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I currently have a tableView and when the cell has been pressed I want to show certain data. The tableView currently has 2 cells 'Set One', 'Set Two'.

If cell with title 'Set One' didSelect then I would like the next View Controller to show the data for this cell.

Here is the data from Core Data:

```
// MusicSet One
defaultMusicSet!.uri = "spotify:track:1puJlKuYGH58SAFgXREUpE"
defaultMusicSet!.duration = 30.0
defaultMusicSet!.starttime = 40.0
defaultMusicSet!.xfade = 10.0
defaultMusicSet!.voiceover = "1.25s Next Up.mp3"

// MusicSet Two
defaultMusicSet!.uri = "spotify:track:59XO64Te17WcmnmMQXQbOj"
defaultMusicSet!.duration = 30.0
defaultMusicSet!.starttime = 34.75
defaultMusicSet!.xfade = 10.0
defaultMusicSet!.voiceover = "1.25s Rest.mp3"
```

In the ViewController I have textFields called 'txtUri', 'txtDuration' etc. Now if I press on the first cell I would like to show //MusicSet One data only, and the same if I press on the 2nd cell it will only show the //MusicSet Two data.

I know the code will have to go inside the tableView (didSelect), but how to show certain information i'm not 100% sure on how to do this?

This won't work, but I kinda know that I need something like this? or similar...

```
let musicData: playViewController?

musicData?.txtUri.text = Music.DefaultMusicSet.uri
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: You have to create and push/show that new 'musicData' VC. If 'txtUri' is a UI element you'll crash though as it has not been created yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add the data MusicSet into an array:

   ```
   var arrMusicSet:[[String:AnyObject]]! = []
   ```
2. Create a Segue from Table Cell to View Controller.
3. Set Segue Identifier in IBInspector.
4. Now when you will press on cell, the segue will get fired, not need of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.
5. Now get the MusicSet according to selected row inside `prepareForSegue` method:

   ```
   // MARK: - Navigation

   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
       if segue.identifier == "MySegueIndentifier" {
           if let destVC = segue.destinationViewController as? MyViewController {

               let selected = self.tableview.indexPathForSelectedRow!.row
               destVC.musicSet = arrMusicSet[selected]                
           }
       }
   }
   ```
6. Define a Variable in View Controller that will take up the forwarded musicSet.

   ```
   var musicSet: MusicSet!
   ```
7. Now assign values to your labels from this `musicSet`.